# Remove Nodes with duplicate XML elements in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I Have an xml that looks like this:

```
myobjects>
<allobjects>
<object name="firstObject" username="usr" pass="pass" specialLine="E:\folder1\files for home  /c /x /waitsecs 30 " default="Yes" binary="1"/>
<object name="secondObjec" username="usr1" pass="thispass" specialLine="E:\folder1\files for home  /c /x /waitsecs 30 " default="no" binary="1" />
<object name="thirdObject" username="usr2" pass="pass1" specialLine="E:\folder1\files for home  /c /x /waitsecs 40 " default="Yes" binary ="0" />
<object name="fourthObject" username="usr3" pass="pass3" specialLine="D:\folder1\files for office  /c /x /waitsecs 50 " default="Yes"  binary="1"/>
<object name="firstobject 1" username="usr4" pass="pass5" specialLine="E:\folder1\files for home  /c /x /waitsecs 30 " default="Yes" binary="0"/>
</allobjects>
<myobjects
```

I want to delete every element with the value `"binary="0"` which I could easily accomplish using the `where-Object` as below:

```
[xml]$myfile = [xml](Get-content path_to_my_file)
 $myfile.myobjects.allobjects.childNodes | where-object{$_.binary -eq 0} |foreach-Object{ do my deletion function}
```

What I want do do next is delete every Node where the `specialLine` value is the same (remain with only one Node for every exactly same `specialLines`). I could get unique `specialLines` using this `$myfile.myobjects.allobjects.object.special | sort-object | get-Unique`

and I just can't find a way to delete nodes and remain with nodes with unique specialLines. I've tried something like this:

```
$myfile.myobjects.allobjects.childNodes | where-object{$myfile.myobjects.allobjects.object.special | sort-object | get-Unique`} |foreach-Object{ do my deletion function}
```

but I think i'm missing something or my approach to this is entirely wrong. Any suggestions or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) on the `specialLine` property and [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)'s `-Skip` parameter to select the nodes to remove.

```
$nodesToRemove = $myfile.myobjects.allobjects.childnodes | Group-Object specialLine |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 }

$nodesToRemove | Foreach-Object {
    $myfile.myobjects.allobjects.RemoveChild($_)
}
```

The idea is to skip the first object in each group (`specialLine` value). If a group is unique, then the entire group will be skipped.

Comment: This works! great explanation on skipping the first object in each group too! That helped me conceptualize what I was missing.